# Bind Datatable to report viewer

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, crystal-reports, datatable, reportviewer

i had using the following code (asp.net + VB) to build a datatable to bind the gridview:

```
Using conn2 As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("XXXX").ConnectionString)
conn2.Open()
cmd.Connection = conn2

sql = "select XXX"
cmd.CommandText = sql
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

Dim dt As New DataTable()

dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Col1_StaffKey", GetType(Int32)))
dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Col1_PostKey", GetType(Int32)))

Dim dr As DataRow

While reader.Read()    '---For each row
     dr = dt.NewRow()
     dr("Col1_StaffKey") = reader("staff_key")
     dr("Col1_PostKey") = reader("post_key")
     dt.Rows.Add(dr)
End While
```

The above code works fine and can bind the gridview, now i want to use the above datatable in report viewer (crystal report)

but when i design the report, it ask me to provide the datasource.

How can I pass and use the existing datatable in report viewer as datasource ?

Thanks
Joe

Answer (score 0):

You can not dynamically assign the Datasource into crystalreport. You must specify the Datasource at time of Design. It may be XML,XSD or any type of Datasource. Pragmatically you can update your datasource.